# Can I make nodejs terminate on unhandled promise rejections?

Tags: node.js

I've got a bug in my code which is triggering the warning:

`DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Is there any way to make Node terminate when these happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`process` will emit an [`unhandledRejection` event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) for these, so:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
    throw error;
});
```

Comment: Instead of `throw error;` maybe would be good to `process.exit(1)`. Just to follow what would be happening in the future, as the message says: `Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy: Throwing an error already causes an exit with a non-zero code. It additionally displays helpful information.

Comment: @Ry- Actually, it was usefull information. Especially inside `.catch`, you can  `console.error` with custom formating and `process.exit(1)` instead of `throw error` to prevent duplicated error output.

Comment: @bigless: That would be “`console.error` with custom formatting and `process.exit(1)` instead of `throw error`”, not “`process.exit(1)` instead of `throw error`”.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure behavior in case of unhandled rejections with `--unhandled-rejections=mode` [flag](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--unhandled-rejectionsmode) or by handling [unhandledRejection](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-unhandledrejection) event.

Starting from Node 15 default unhandled rejections mode is `throw` which means that it will raise [uncaughtException](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-uncaughtexception), which in turn will shut down your node server. So that will behave automatically in the way that you want.