pm2 + axios errors in async function
I'm using pm2 to ensure a nodejs service is always running.
Now I have the issue though that axios errors inside an async function don't properly throw and terminate the process (so pm2 can restart it) but it gets stuck in a weird state instead where the process is still running but nothing is happening anymore.
How do I properly handle axios errors inside async functions so pm2 can do it's job?

It's unclear what  happens in the app. This depends where and how async function is used. You may need to explicitly process.exit in unhandledRejection in older node versions, otherwise uncaught promise errors should make the app to exit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752057/can-i-make-nodejs-terminate-on-unhandled-promise-rejections . If an error is not an exception you should always have catch for it
